# Trigger en plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, trigger

al inserta un nuevo dato en una tabla para probar el trigger me arroja el siguiente error:

```
ORA-04091: la tabla SYSTEM.VENTA está mutando, puede que el disparador/la función no puedan verla
ORA-06512: en "SYSTEM.T2", línea 2
ORA-06512: en "SYSTEM.T2", línea 8
ORA-04088: error durante la ejecución del disparador 'SYSTEM.T2'
```

Mi trigger es:

```
create or replace trigger t2 
after insert on venta
for each row
declare cursor valor is
select p.precio,v.monto
from patente p,venta v
where p.numero_patente = v.numero_patente;
prec patente.precio%type;
mont venta.monto%type;
begin 
open valor;
fetch valor into prec,mont;
while valor%found
loop
if mont<prec then update patente set cantidad=cantidad+1 where numero_patente = :new.numero_patente;
else raise_application_error(-20201,'Error el precio pagado es menor al precio inicial');
end if;
fetch valor into prec,mont;
end loop;
close valor;
end t2;
```

Creo que el problema es al asignar el precio a una nueva variable, el problema es que no se como solucionarlo para completar la comparacion entre los precios(mont y prec).

Comment: ¡Que indentación, por dios!, jaja. Indenta tu código, solo para hacerlo más legible. En lo que he podido ver, no hay nada en tu código que pueda lanzar directamente este error. Habría que ver que _triggers_ tiene la tabla `patente`. Vendría bien también saber qué instrucción es la que estás ejecutando que te da idea que es este _trigger_ el culpable.

Comment: @looper la indentación es **fundamental** para que los humanos comprendamos lo que el código está intentando hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es que **NO** es una buena práctica crear tablas en el esquema SYSTEM, ya que este es el uno de los esquema nativos de Oracle (el otro es SYS) para la administración de la base de datos, y el único que debe tener acceso es un DBA, nunca los desarrolladores.

Segundo, el error ORA-04091 lo que indica que se está intentando realizar un SELECT sobre la tabla en la cual reside el trigger, y eso no es válido porque en el instante de tiempo que se dispara o lanza el trigger la tabla no está en un estado estable y por lo tanto no cumple con las condiciones ACID.

Suponiendo que la tabla PATENTE tiene como llave primaria la columna NUMERO_PATENTE entonces puede cambiar el trigger a:

```
create or replace trigger t2
after insert on venta
for each row
declare
  prec   patente.precio%type;
begin 
  select p.precio
  into prec
  from PATENTE p,
  where p.NUMERO_PATENTE =:new.numero_patente;
  --
  if :new.monto<prec then 
     update patente 
     set cantidad=cantidad+1 
     where numero_patente = :new.numero_patente;
  else 
     raise_application_error(-20201,'Error el precio pagado es menor al precio inicial');
  end if;
end t2;
```