# Error ORA-04091 al ejecutar un trigger

Tags: plsql

Tengo las siguientes tablas entre otras:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS (
CODIGO  NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
PRECIO   NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE  LINEAS    (   
NUM NUMBER(2,0), 
NUM_PEDIDO NUMBER(5,0), 
PRODUCTO NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL , 
CANTIDAD NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL , 
IMPORTE NUMBER(6,2), 
 CONSTRAINT DETALLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (NUM, NUM_PEDIDO) , 
 CONSTRAINT PEDIDO_FK FOREIGN KEY (NUM_PEDIDO)
  REFERENCES  PEDIDOS (NUM) , 
 CONSTRAINT PRODUCTO_FK FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTO)
  REFERENCES  PRODUCTOS (CODIGO) 
   );
```

He hecho un trigger para actualizar importe con el valor cantidad de LINEAS y precio de PRODUCTOS. Es:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_IMPORTE_LINEAS
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON LINEAS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING THEN
      UPDATE LINEAS SET IMPORTE = (:NEW.CANTIDAD * (SELECT PRECIO FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE CODIGO =PRODUCTO));
   ELSIF UPDATING THEN
     UPDATE LINEAS SET IMPORTE = (:NEW.CANTIDAD * (SELECT PRECIO FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE CODIGO =PRODUCTO));
   END IF;
END;
```

No me da problemas al compilar, pero al insertar una fila me da error:

> ORA-04091: table TAREA5.LINEAS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
> ORA-06512: at "TAREA5.TRIG_IMPORTE_LINEAS", line 3
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TAREA5.TRIG_IMPORTE_LINEAS'

```
1. INSERT INTO LINEAS VALUES (1,12,10001, 4, 90);
```

He probado diferentes configuraciones y no he conseguido que funcione.

Comment: te he editado el código acéptalo para que te puedan ayudar mejor :)

Comment: Deberías pasarte por [ask] y realizar el [tour], y así conseguir tus primeras medallas y comprender como funciona esta comunidad

Comment: El error te dice que la tabla está mutando (cambiando), es decir: no podés tocar una tabla para un INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE cuando tu trigger está relacionado a esa misma tabla. Revisa las preguntas [que ya están en este sitio](/search?q=ORA-04091).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Trigger en plsql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269898/trigger-en-plsql)